# Managing HTML resources (CSS, JS files) in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, grails, spring-mvc, resources

Is it possible to manage HTML resources in Spring MVC similar to grails-resources?

Similar to this :  http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2011/09/12/optimising-your-application-with-grails-resources-plugin/

For example : In Grails,  modules is specified as

```
modules = {  
     common {  
        resource url:"css/main.css"  
        resource url:"js/jquery.js"  
     }  
}
```

and in HTML, this tag is specified with module name to load all files.

```
<r:require module="common"/>
```

So I was wondering is there any way I can do similar kind of stuff in Spring MVC with `<mvc:resources>` or any other option?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the meaning of "to manage HTML resources".
I am assuming you want to access the static HTML page in Spring. Am I right? Please give feedback so that I can answer your question.

Comment: You could click the provided link. The question is about CSS, JS, and images.

Comment: @JapanTrivedi : Hi Japan,  I added more description above.  I want to manage css and js files in spring mvc, with grails example i showed above.

Comment: @Aby just read the answer by Hoang. I recommend you to do the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: surely**. But I think the real question is "how?" :)

Spring MVC is the base that Grails built on, so it can do what Grails can do. Grails-resources is just an utility that Grails make to help developing works easier. If you want to do the same in Spring, you must do some work.

Firstly, Spring MVC has a way to expose resources ([reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources), Chapter 17.15.6, "Configuring Serving of Resources"); for example:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
```

The above line expose every files in `[Web folder]/images/` as resource and can be requested by web browsers.

Second, to embed the resource into HTMLs as easy like Grails, you must combine Spring [with some other view technologies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html), like sitemesh, freemarker/velocity/JSP... (which Grails do behind the scene for you). Instead of ***grails tag***, now you have ***freemarker's or Velocity's macros***. But I would recommend writing some of your own custom macros, since the built-in one is not always good.

I have used both Grails and Spring MVC. I appreciate Grails' effort to make developer life easier, but with Spring things are a bit different. With Spring, you'll get to write some more code, make some more choices (in Grails they were chosen for you as "default", and is "invisible" if you don't want to customize). As the pay-off, you are **forced** to be more awared with the under-lying mechanism, which is a good thing.

I have used sitemesh for layout, and freemarker as a HTML-rendering engine for several web projects, and they works pretty well.

---

**UPDATE:**

I want to make clear that `mvc:resources` is not the full answer to your problem. It's just the part of ***exposing*** the web resources out for browsers to get. With Grails, this is already made by default, but it's not true for Spring. You must specify that the content in folder 'images' are resources, and they can be accessed by the url `http://your-domain-name/context-name/images/image-name` . As saying, Spring is a lot more explicit than Grails.

Another thing is template engine. Library Sitemesh is a popular choice when working with Spring (it's also the default for Grails), so it isn't a lot different (mostly it's about syntax). **The main purpose of template engine is to "fill in" your htmls with dynamic data**, and I'm going to show you... a bit of it.

Please be aware that, to make a tutorial that fulfill your example is exceed the scope of an answer. Also, Spring enable many relevant solutions, which means different developers may have different way of organization/ config. But to give you a feeling, I'll make a quick example (I'm using freemarker to make this example):

In file: common.ftl, I have:

```
<#macro commonInclude>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${rc.getContextUrl('/js/jquery.js')}"></script>     
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${rc.getContextUrl('css/main.css')}" />
</#macro>
```

With a little more config, then in view files I can call:

```
<@common.commonInclude />
```

And it will render the code you want.

As you see, the main difference is their syntax. Grails allow a cleaner style, while Spring give you a more "explicit" style which will benefit if you want to customize things.

- Bonus: If you are looking for a replacement for `Grails layout`, take a quick search for "Spring and Sitemesh" and you may find it.

Comment: Thanks Long for replying.  Can i implement similar kind of example which is shown above as grails example using <mvc:resources> ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can. Its the best answer and should solve your problem.

Comment: @JapanTrivedi : is there any examples for <mvc:resources> i can look into ?

Comment: There is nothing like an example... Whatever is written here is the example for **<mvc: resources>**

Comment: @JapanTrivedi: thanks for your appreciation. I just try my best to explain. Spring framework is very complex, and I think it will take a while for people to get used to

Comment: @HoàngLong you are welcome. I totally agree with you. Its very difficult for a newcomer to get used to Spring Terminologies. :)

Comment: @HoàngLong :  Thanks for updating your answer.  Seems like mvc:resources is not a  option to consider now.  I can think more about macro option.

Comment: @Aby: if you have anything unclear, just drop a question. Telling more about your true purpose may help,too.

Comment: @HoàngLong :  I tried looking for sitemesh. But didnt found any useful stuff for html resources, which you mentioned above. The way grails support HTML resources is pretty awesome.  They support yuicompression + module kind of structure.  Which will load specific scripts on different pages and also do compression.  Now doing similar stuff in spring is complex.

Comment: @Aby: I must agree with you that Grails' support for quick-developing is awesome. There's nothing to be doubted about that. But since Grails was built on top of Spring, it could be very handy if you know the basics. Spring's heavy configuration comes with a compensation: the readiness for changing and REFACTORING. If you just use Grails to build common web application, you won't need to bother about it; but if you want to build something lasts and CHANGE OFTEN, I think you'd better using Spring because it provide better tools for REFACTORING.

Comment: @Aby: about compressing javascript resources,you can look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211965/unobtrusive-way-to-combine-and-compress-javascript-css-for-java-spring-maven-app . It  requires Maven & configurations - something isn't as simple as installing a Grails plugin. Just to illustrate that you can do anything with Spring - more work at first,but easier to customize.

Comment: +1, this was useful to me. (Specifically the simple `<mvc:resources>` example.) I took the liberty to update the Spring docs reference (section 17.15.6 in latest version).

Answer (score 0):

> grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {

    resourceHttpRequestHandler(ResourceHttpRequestHandler) {
        locations = ['file:/D:/fupload/']
    }

    resourceHandlerAdapter(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter)

    resourceHandlerMapping(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) {
        urlMap = ['/fupload/**':'resourceHttpRequestHandler']
    }
}
```

Comment: This means, for example, that when you access http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload/img/a.jpg, if the file is on the west side of the webapp placed under the Tomcat container, it can be accessed directly, but I want him to have access to d:/upload/img/a.jpg

Comment: This is something from Grails. If you are springmvc, you should configure the XML file.   <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>