# Minify resource files with IIS, when using Java and .JSP

Tags: iis, java, compression, jsp

I was recommended that I move this question from StackOverflow to here.

I am running a web site on a server with Tomcat and IIS. I use .JSP and Java in the back end.

I don't know how to configure IIS to automatically minify resource files (CSS, JavaScript, images) when using .JSP. I have found a few suggested solutions online, but they all apply to IIS and .ASP.

I added the "compression" tag to this post because there is no "minification" tag available, but I am not referring to gzip compression, but removing white spaces, merging resources for faster download etc.

Could anyone help me figure out how to configure IIS to minify resource files with .JSP? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why you were told to ask this question here. Minifying your resource files is a programming/web design problem (it's not something you'd ***WANT*** your web server to be doing on the fly - you're making your server work harder to parse and rewrite content when you're trying to save resources already - in what world does that make sense?)

Comment: Actually I do want my server to do this on the fly, for reasons you can read about here: https://code.google.com/p/webutilities/.  The issue is that I was able to make Tomcat minify on the fly, as shown in the link above, but it does not work because I am using IIS. So I need to make IIS to minify the resources. I thought it's okay to post here because there are IIS, Java and JSP tags on this forum. Hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to minify your content when you can get IIS to cache and compress it :-) Provide details about the OS version and on how you've configured IIS and I'll try to explain

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The website is running on a server with Tomcat proxied by IIS6 - through ISAPI. IIS6 is already set to do gzip compression, but I am looking for a solution to set IIS or ISAPI to minify&combine resources on the fly, for JSP pages. Thank you!

Comment: If there is a possibility to change the Java app, don't bother with IIS go with [JAWR](https://jawr.java.net/). It does the same job from the Java side (and perhaps a little more). I do not expect the changes to include JAWR will be that big (although this really depends on the application).

Answer (score 0):

Minification a process which combines multiple CSS or JS files to a single file and perform process of compression(whitespace removal) and obfuscation(JS) is an ideal build time solution, rather than a run time solution. While using Tomcat with IIS, it will be good to have some thing like this:

- Use WRO4J as a maven build time plugin. Create an attribute like
  devmode=true or false. In JSP's have if else condition to define
  groups to add multiple CSS/JS or Single based on the devmode value.
- While deploying use devmode = false. This with maven configuration will compile JSP with single CSS/JS files.

In IIS, configure a separate VD and map your static resources of war to it. Write a rewrite rule to instruct IIS to serve the static resources. Enable static compression.

The above said configuration will take less load on the CPU.

Some links of interest could be:
https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin

[Unobtrusive way to combine and compress javascript/css for java/spring/maven applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211965/unobtrusive-way-to-combine-and-compress-javascript-css-for-java-spring-maven-app)